# How to change a JTable's empty space color?

Tags: java, colors

I'm trying to make a `JTable` in my app. So far I've been able to change almost all the settings I need, except for the color of the empty space. I want to change the color so it is the same as the row's background color. How do you do that?

[image]

Comment: That part is the parent container of the `JTable`. Since you didn't post any code, I can't be more specific. I think you should consider posting a [mcve]. You can [edit] your question and post some code that I can copy, compile and run and which will demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Hello.This is just the default JTable with a couple of model modifications. You can create a new JFrame in your IDE and place a table with the gui swing editor, and you'll have your minimal reproducible example.

Comment: (1-) *You can create a new JFrame in your IDE and place a table with the gui swing editor, and you'll have your minimal reproducible example* - that is NOT the way the forum works. You are the one who is asking the question. If you want people to help then you post your "MRE" demonstrating the problem based on the code you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class TableExample {
    JFrame f;

    TableExample() {
        f = new JFrame();
        String data[][] = { { "101", "Amit", "670000" }, { "102", "Jai", "780000" }, { "101", "Sachin", "700000" } };
        String column[] = { "ID", "NAME", "SALARY" };
        JTable jt = new JTable(data, column);

        jt.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {// alternate background color for rows
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                if (!isSelected)
                    c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.lightGray);
                return c;
            };
        });

        jt.setBackground(Color.red);
        jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        f.add(sp);
        f.setSize(300, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Tutai. After reviewing your code, I noticed what I was lacking: ticking the `fillsViewportHeigth` option in the component's properties. Sadly , the option's name was not really self explanatory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the opaque in jtable properties

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).